# Parsing JSON from Requests drops start of json file

Tags: json, parsing, flask, python-requests

I have a json file that I provide via flask, and I'd like to parse it from a requests object, but I can't get the full data back.  I get a broken json file.  What I get is about one third of the way through the file to the end.

I get different answers whether I use `r.json()` or `json.loads(r.text)`from the simple get request:

```
r = requests.get("url/api")
```

If I stream it manually, I can see the start of the file

```
r= requests.get("url/api", stream=True)
r.raw.read(1000).decode('utf-8')
```

And I successfully save down the file as here [how to parse big requests object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694907/download-large-file-in-python-with-requests), but the problem persists when I try to then upload the file using `json.load(local_filename)`

The shape of my json file is:

```
[{"key1":"value1_1", "key2":"value2_1"},{"key1":"value1_2", "key2":"value2_2"}.......]
```

This is how I provide the json from flask

```
@app.route('/api', methods=['GET'])
def provide_json():
    with open('record_file.json') as f:
        record_file = json.load(f)
    return json.dumps(record_file)
```

I've checked that my json file is valid, and I'm also assuming that my flask code with throw an exception is I wasn't delivering a valid json file because I've used `json.dumps`.  Is that right?  I've also tried wrapping the json file in flask with `return json.dumps({"data_file":record_file})` but it doesn't change the problem.

Comment: ```"key2":"value2_1}``` this json file is missing double quotes. Are you sure the file saved is correct?

Comment: @jen thanks! my typo here, not in the json.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning list which is not a valid response for flask. Try this

```
from flask import jsonify
@app.route('/api', methods=['GET'])
def provide_json():
    with open('record_file.json') as f:
        record_file = json.load(f)
    return jsonify({"data": record_file})
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, the problem persists.  I did note that I had made wrapped the list in a {}, so your suggestion is a change from providing via jsonify instead of json.dumps, but the problem persists.  It feels like this isn't a problem at the end of providing the file.